# Подключение через proxy Delphi XE

Tags: delphi

Как имея прокси (один из списка) им воспользоваться, чтобы обратиться к сервису укорачивания ссылок. Если подключение не удалюсь, то есть прокси не рабочий, то брать следующий proxy.

Это мой первый опыт в работе с сетями.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Edit2.Text:=Edit1.Text;
  Edit3.Text:=Edit1.Text;

 if edit1.Text<>' ' then
   Edit2.Text:=idHTTP1.Get('http://сервис_укорачивания_ссылок/api-create.php?url=' + edit1.text);

 if edit3.Text<>' ' then
   Edit3.Text:=idHTTP1.Get('http://сервис_укорачивания_ссылок/api?url=' + edit3.text);
end;
```

Comment: Опять каша ... ничего не понятно. У вас в Мемо список проксей, что должно происходить дальше?

Comment: @ Kromster, Обновила вопрос: Посмотрите в теме.

Comment: Ничего не прояснилось. У вас есть список прокси, как вы им хотите воспользоваться дальше? Что такое "все запросы idHTTP1.Get - обрабатываются через прокси" - это ваш вопрос или утверждение? При чем тут сервис_укорачивания_ссылок?

Comment: @ KromsterПростыми словами говоря - смена ip в программе при подключении к сайту. А сервис укорачивания - это для теста. То есть я ввожу ссылку в программе в edit1 и она обрабатывается (в данном случае через два сервиса - укорачивания ссылок) и результат выводиться в edit2 и edit3.

Comment: То есть ваш вопрос в том, как имея прокси (один из вашего списка) им воспользоваться, чтобы обратиться к сервису укорачивания ссылок, так?

Comment: @ Kromster, Да, вот это цель задачи.

Comment: Тогда так в вопросе и напишите. Уберите всё лишнее про Мемо и кнопки, оставьте только суть конкретной проблемы.

Comment: @Kromster, Сделала, сможете теперь подсказать ?